# django order by isnull value?

Tags: django, isnull

i have a datetime field which can be null and id like to do qs.order_by('field__isnull', 'name') but this results in:

`Join on field 'field' not permitted. Did you misspell 'isnull' for the lookup type?`

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there may be better ways, but one possibility is to annotate your queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count
qs.annotate(null_count=Count('field_name')).order_by('null_count')
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, Django doesn't provide function `IsNull`, that could be used for ordering, annotations, etc.
(It does provide a query lookup, but it may only be used for filtering.)
You may however define the function yourself:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Func

class IsNull(Func):
    _output_field = BooleanField()
    arity = 1
    template = '%(expressions)s IS NULL'
```

Now you may order your queryset like this:

```
qs.order_by(IsNull('field'), 'name')
```

Comment: Interesting ne take on the problem!

Answer (score -3):

I'm hoping that your model is something like this:

```
    date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

If    True
then you can do this:

```
qs.order_by('-date_deleted')
```

Comment: This imposes a sorting by date for non-null values, instead the asker is just wanting 2 groups, null and non-null.