# Django: meta class order ignoring NULL

Tags: python, django, model, metaclass

I need to sort queryset using Django model's meta class.
I've defined it like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

Some records have null as its "order" value.
If I get queryset, then the records that has null as order value are placed at beginning of result.
I just want to place such records at the end of queryset.

I've checked some articles for this purpose.
[django order by isnull value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648736/django-order-by-isnull-value)
[Django : Order by position ignoring NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235209/django-order-by-position-ignoring-null)

But I need it to be done using Django model's Meta class.
Is there any idea to do it via Meta class?

Regards
Philip

Comment: It is not possible using the `ordering` attribute, as it only takes strings and not callables; why do you have to do it from the `Meta` class? You can write a custom manager to do what you need; or with aggregation as in the [question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235209/django-order-by-position-ignoring-null)

Comment: Try ```ordering=['-order']```.

Comment: Thanks Burhan. custom manager would work for me well.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is too old, but according django's docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/) it's possible to use query expressions to handle ordering leaving null values to the end of queryset.

I've successfully done those ordenation settings:

**class MyModel(models.Model):**

```
fieldA = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fieldB = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fieldA_or_B = models.IntegerField(choices=[...], default=None, null=False, blank=False)
```

**class Meta:**

`ordering = [F("fieldA").asc(nulls_last=True), F("fieldB").asc(nulls_last=True)`]

Hope it helps!